Can I access data from single HDD of RAID-1 (Software based RAID)?
I had a machine running Linux Server (Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS) on a M.2 NVMe SSD, and have connected 2 four TB NAS HDD with software based RAID-1 configuration (Linux RAID1 and formatted as EXT4 partition). Now for some unknown reason, SSD is not getting detected by motherboard, and I have to replace this SSD.
Now, my question is, can I connect single NAS HDD to another PC and copy data from it?
How can I get access to the data from NAS HDDs?
EDIT
Here, by NAS HHD, I mean Seagate IronWolf NAS 3.5" HDD.
And both the HDDs are paired to single drive with Linux RAID-1 configuration.

Please clarify your question. You mention NAS HDD and a software RAID1. What is it? A NAS (which is a separate device) or a raid1 inside the computer? It can't be both. It is a bit confusing now. You can edit your question to improve it.

In theory the answer is yes, and I've done it in the far distant past, but it can depend on how the NAS sets up the drives.

Yes, if your operating system supports the file system used, you should be able to access data from a single disk with RAID 1.
Ext4 has been present for well over a dozen years and if Ubuntu does not see the partitions, it will indicate some problem with the logical structures.
If you want to recover data from this disk, it is worth mounting it in read-only mode.
